# Launchctl not starting wso2 servers

Tags: macos, wso2, launchd

I am trying to set up a couple of daemons on MAC OS X for wso2 servers: ESB, AM, AS, etc.
I am encountering the following error in /var/log/system.log and processes don't start:

```
no application identifier provided, can't use provisioning profiles
```

Here is the plist file located in /Library/LaunchDaemons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
<string>org.wso2.am</string>
<key>Program</key>
<string>/software/wso2am/bin/wso2server.sh</string>

<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Additional info:

- MAC OS X El Capitan, v10.11.6 (15G31)
- launchctl version:
  Darwin Bootstrapper Version 3.4.0: Sat Apr  2 20:54:16 PDT 2016; root:TempContent/launchd/RELEASE_X86_64

  - wso2 version doesn't matter (I tried other software also).

Any recommendation?

Thanks